# How to solve flsgetvalue() heap corruption in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, heap-corruption

I have an output function which writes some parameters to a file with a loop. I call the function several times before it crashes and it functions properly. The loop returns the amount of times specified in the "count" parameter. When the count is 6000, it crashes at 5960. The function doesn't crash at previous calls, which pass a lower count to the function.

The error refers me to tidtable.c and points the lines:

```
_CRTIMP PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION __cdecl __set_flsgetvalue()
{
#ifdef _M_IX86
    PFLS_GETVALUE_FUNCTION flsGetValue = FLS_GETVALUE; // <---exactly Here
    if (!flsGetValue)
    {
        flsGetValue = DecodePointer(gpFlsGetValue);
        TlsSetValue(__getvalueindex, flsGetValue);
    }
    return flsGetValue;
```

I initialize the only dynamically allocated parameter, pntr in the function using the following template:

```
template <typename T>
T *AllocateDynamicVector(int nRows){
    T *dynamicArray;

    dynamicArray = new T[nRows];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ ){
        dynamicArray[i]= 0;
    }
    return dynamicArray;
}
```

The initialization from the main is:

```
    int* pntrPlane     = AllocateDynamicVector<int>(2*numberOfCells);
Writer(myfile,ss,"123","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0",2*numberOfCells,lineInfo,1,pntrPlane);
```

The code is to be found below:

```
void Writer (ofstream &myfile, stringstream &ss, std::string type, std::string id1, std::string id2, std::string id3,
       std::string id4,std::string id5,std::string id6,std::string id7,std::string id8, int count, 
       int lineInfo[2], int lineNum, int* pntr){
           if(myfile.is_open()){
               for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
                   if (type == "123"){
                       cout<<"I'm here!"<<" "<<i<<endl;
                   }
                   ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(80)<<lineInfo[0]; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(73)<<"1D"; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(56)<<id1.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(48)<<id2.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(40)<<id3.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(32)<<id4.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(24)<<id5.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(16)<<lineInfo[1]; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(8)<<type.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   myfile<<ss.str()<<endl; ss.clear();
                   pntr[i] = lineInfo[0];
                   lineInfo[0]++;
                   ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(80)<<lineInfo[0]; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(73)<<"0D"; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(40)<<id6.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(32)<<lineNum; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(24)<<id8.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(16)<<"0"; ss.seekp(0);
                   ss<<setw(8)<<type.c_str(); ss.seekp(0);
                   myfile<<ss.str()<<endl; ss.clear();
                   lineInfo[0]++;
                   lineInfo[1] = lineInfo[1] + lineNum;
               }
           }
}
```

How can I avoid that problem??

Note: If I run program without debugging, then the error vanishes.

Edit: Detailed description of the problem: I'm generating an output file using the function above several times. I send parameters to the function, including a dynamic integer vector, and write a number into it at every iteration. During the execution of this function with a set of parameters, it gives a heap corruption error "Critical error detected c0000374". The strange thins is that it doesn't give error with other instances.

Comment: Can you describe in better detail what your error is? And maybe post the entire code too? (Somewhere?)

Comment: @C Johnson I tried to add some more detail in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but without reproducable code I have no way to help you. I have no call-stack, I have no data to send into your function, I have no working code that I can compile and run. You are using the standard libraries here which are pretty much bullet-proof. Which means the problem is most likely your own.

To debug this I would do this:

1. Reduce your code back to basically nothing by commenting out code.
2. Get the code run to the end by executing a basic shell. Make sure it runs with no errors.
3. In visual studio turn on all 'break on exceptions' in the debug menu options. This is otherwise known as break on first chance exceptions.
4. Uncomment your code one line at a time and run it to completion. Make sure it runs without errors.
5. Repeat step 4 until you uncomment all your code.
6. make sure your debug configuration is linked against debug libraries and your release configuration is linked against release libraries.

Comment: @C Johnson. Thank you, I understand that it's almost impossible to suggest a solution to this problem remotely.